# Run and Print Crystal Report from VBA

Tags: vba, crystal-reports, excel, crystal-reports-xi

I want to automate CR report printing from VB/VBA.

I have Crystal Reports XI Developer installed and .rpt files (some requiring parameters) to run and send to a printer, without requiring any user intervention.

Now, I stuck at the very first step, adding the correct libraries. There are probably about 50 libraries or so that start with Crystal Reports or Business Objects, and I have no idea which ones I need.

Any pointers to get me started would be appreciated.

Thanks
Martin

Comment: When you say VB/VBA can you work with a VB.Net Solution? If so I have some code that will take your Crystal Report and export it to a PDF file behind the scenes and then send that file directly to the default printer (no user interaction).

Comment: Unfortuneately I'm stuck with VB6/VBA. Maybe you could still post your solution - right now its not so much about the details, its more that I can't seem to find a starting point, and the VB.NET solution might be similar enough to get me started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem.

`CRAXDRT.dll` aka *Crystal Reports ActiveX Designer Run Time Library* is the correct library.

Here is some sample code:

```
Dim CR As New CRAXDRT.Application
Dim rep As CRAXDRT.Report
Set rep = CR.OpenReport(Range("CRpath"))
rep.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue "Boston"
rep.ParameterFields(2).AddCurrentValue "Cars"
rep.Database.Tables(1).ConnectionProperties("Password").Value = "pw12345"
rep.ReadRecords
rep.PrintOut promptUser:=False, numberOfCopy:=1 ' promptUser:=True doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your budget, but I recommend a 3rd party program called Visual Cut (http://www.milletsoftware.com/Visual_CUT.htm).  Using either a command line or the built-in GUI, you can process Crystal Report files pretty much any way you want, including PDFing, emailing, and even printing directly to a printer. So you can skip the VBA entirely if you want.

It's been around since 2002 and the developer has been continuously adding custom features to it by customer request, so it suffers a little from 'feature creep'.  However, the manual (downloadable for free from the website) does a good job of keeping it all in perspective.  Also, if you get the maintenance agreement, the developer is very responsive.  In my case, he usually returns my calls within the day.

**(This isn't the developer talking, just a satisfied customer)*